Вёрстка галереи фото на flex по заданному html-шаблону
Как сверстать галерею фото на flex, используя только CSS по заданному html-шаблону, который нельзя менять?
Задача:

Первый вариант строго по 4 фото в ряд, но чтобы не зависело от ширины экрана. То есть при ширине 1000px ширина фото должна быть 250px c отступами и рамками, при ширине 1200 — 300 на каждое фото, тогда их будет по 4 в ряд и т. д.

Второй вариант с переменным количеством в ряду (это зависит от ширины экрана), но с фиксированным размером рамки 150px на 150px.

Фото разных (любых) размеров и пропорций, добавив рамку чтобы смотрелось ровно.

Html-разметка для обоих вариантов должна быть одинаковой.


Решение необходимо сделать на основе этого шаблона:
<style>.wrap div  {border: 1px solid grey;padding:3px}</style>
<div class="wrap">
<div><img src="01.jpg" alt="Изображение 01"></div>
<div><img src="02.jpg" alt="Изображение 02"></div>
<div><img src="03.jpg" alt="Изображение 03"></div>
<div><img src="04.jpg" alt="Изображение 04"></div>
<div><img src="05.jpg" alt="Изображение 05"></div>
<div><img src="06.jpg" alt="Изображение 06"></div>
<div class="seven"><img src="07.jpg" alt="Изображение 07"></div>
<div><img src="08.jpg" alt="Изображение 08"></div>
</div>


У нас тут сообщество, которое помогает разобраться в проблеме и решить вопрос, который вы пытались решить, но не справились. Вы же поставили вопрос так, словно необходимо выполнить работу для вас. Не надо так.

Про динамическую ширину блоков в calc ответили, чтобы их по 4 вписывалось. Но дополню, что с такой постановкой задачи там проще использовать display: grid.

@AlexKrass, ой, я не совсем понял, я думал речь идёт про два ряда, когда в вопросе две задачи.

Чисто математически у 1000 пикселей не может быть 4 блока по 250 пикселей с отступами)).

Не совсем понятно каким должны быть последующие ряды.
Для того чтобы разбить все изображение по рядам - используй flex-wrap
Чтобы красиво вписать изображение в квадрат - fit-object
Чтобы первые 4 изображение были одним стилем, а остальные другим - используй :nth-child


.wrap{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  width:100%;
   justify-content:space-around; 
}
.wrap>div>img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  object-fit:cover;
  
}
.wrap>div{
  border-radius:15px;
  margin:5px;
  overflow:hidden;
  
}
.wrap>div:nth-child(-n+4){
  width:calc(25% - 10px);
  height:300px;
}

.wrap>div:nth-child(n+5){
/*   display:none; */
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  
}
 <div class="wrap">
    <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/p1/800/600" alt="Изображение 01"></div>
    <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/p2/600/300" alt="Изображение 02"></div>
    <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/p3/600/800" alt="Изображение 03"></div>
    <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/p4/800/600" alt="Изображение 04"></div>
    <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/p5/800/600" alt="Изображение 05"></div>
    <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/p6/800/600" alt="Изображение 06"></div>
    <div class="seven"><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/p7/800/600" alt="Изображение 07"></div>
    <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/p8/800/600" alt="Изображение 08"></div>
    </div>




вместо object-fit: cover
лучше применить  object-fit:contain
поскольку в противном случае картинка будет обрезаться

необходимо, чтобы фото из первого ряда шли строго по 4 фото в ряд, пропорционально сжимаясь на узких экранах, остальные 4 фото не должны сжиматься, но могут переноситься  на следующий ряд
в варианте предложенном выше, первые 3 фото сжимаются, но не переносятся, а четвертое фото которое должно вести себя также как первые 3, все равно переносится, хотя и сжимается

@Yuriy Да не может такого быть. Покажите скриншот. Учтите, что в примере решены обе задачи, указанные выше.

@Yuriy про object-fit - тут, как говорится, можете использовать на свой вкус. Зависит от изображения.

спасибо за помощь, проблему решил следующим образом
вместо   width:calc(25% - 10px);
указал   width:calc(25% - 12px);
поскольку у меня кроме margin:5px для  div были еще установлены 2 размера рамок : 1px для внешнего контейнера wrap и столько же для внутренней рамки div

Если у вас для блока Margin:5px; и border:1px - то в call сумма этих значений, умноженная на 2.
Если у вас есть ещё padding во wrap, то надо добавить 2/4 (12,5px), ну или 13, с учётом justify-content лишние полпикселя будут отцентрованы. Внешние модификация врапа, навроде border - не учитываюся. Ещё лайфхак - если нужен border без ширины, я использую box-shadow.

в более простых случаях, можно попробовать для div использовать box-sizing: border-box; width:25%;
то есть когда требуется реализовать лишь 1 вариант - выстроить все фото строго по 4 штуки
